# groovy sort with comparator syntax

Tags: sorting, groovy

I am just getting my feet wet with gremlin. I understand that gremlin is based on groovy. I found the documentation [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#sort%28groovy.lang.Closure%29), but I am still not sure what the syntax means.

I am a bit confused as to how the syntax of sort with a comparator works:

```
m.sort{a,b -> a.value <=> b.value}
```

Could someone explain what all the different bits between the `{` and `}` mean?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

When the `Closure` used by `sort` has two parameters, it acts like a traditional [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). That is, for each comparison that is done during the sort, between two elements `a` and `b`, it *returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second*.

In your particular scenario, the comparison is the result of using the [spaceship operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaceship_operator) `<=>`. In other words, you are effectively sorting your elements in **ascending** order.

For example, if you had the list `[ 3, 2, 1 ]`, the result of using that sort [would be](http://ideone.com/491mY) `[ 1, 2, 3 ]`.

Thus, `m.sort{a,b -> a.value <=> b.value}` is *roughly* the equivalent of using the following `compare` function:

```
int compare(a, b) {
  if (a < b) {
    return -1;
  } else if (a > b) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: So, the `a,b ->`, simply passes the values `a` and `b` to the comparator?

Comment: @F21: Yes, sort of. It's like a function that takes two parameters and is used to sort according to the function body which returns the spaceship operator.

Comment: i didnt get what is a `<=>` spaceship operator. Wiki was of not much help

Answer (score 9):

The spaceship operator `<=>` is an overloaded operator and represents `compareTo()`. Basically `a<=>b` is the same as `a.compareTo(b)`

The example that you gave is using the `sort()` function with a closure (like lambda in Java8). The syntax for it is the following:

> .method{`closureParameters` -> `statements`}

So your example is using the `sort()` function with a [closure](http://www.groovy-lang.org/closures.html), inside that closure you use the spaceship (comparator) operator

More about operator overloading [here](http://groovy.jmiguel.eu/groovy.codehaus.org/Operator+Overloading.html)