# How to get tuples in gremlin?

Tags: titan, gremlin

How can I get Gremlin return a tuple. I want to get 2 attributes from vertices at a time and then sort these tuples on one of the attributes. How can I do that.

Also how can analytics be applied to titan graphs....

Comment: I was able to answer the first part of your question about tuples/sorting, but the "analytics question" is a too broad as others have noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your question regarding tuples - just transform to a two (or more) item list of your properties:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g.V.has('age').transform{[it.name,it.age]} 
==>[marko, 29]
==>[vadas, 27]
==>[josh, 32]
==>[peter, 35]
```

then to sort, just use `order` step and pick the item in the tuple to order by...in this case "name":

```
gremlin> g.V.has('age').transform{[it.name,it.age]}.order{it.a[0]<=>it.b[0]}
==>[josh, 32]
==>[marko, 29]
==>[peter, 35]
==>[vadas, 27]
```

and in this case "age":

```
gremlin> g.V.has('age').transform{[it.name,it.age]}.order{it.a[1]<=>it.b[1]}    
==>[vadas, 27]
==>[marko, 29]
==>[josh, 32]
==>[peter, 35]
```

Comment: what is a and b in order, didnt catch that one. Thanks

Comment: `a` and `b` are the arguments to a compare function.  you can read more about it here as it pertains to [groovy sort](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12574669/1831717)

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Hope you help me in future too. And there somehow I can apply machine learning algorithms and page ranks to graphs