# Groovy Custom Comparator

Tags: sorting, groovy

I try to figure out how build custom `Comparator`. I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574669/groovy-sort-with-comparator-syntax) but I'm still stuck. I want to sort files using a few `ArrayList`s, for example:

my Files:

```
 def files = ['author/foo.pkb', 'author/foo.pks', 
'version/test1.pks', 'version/test1.pkb', 'Somethink/foo.sql']
```

My order list:

```
def my_order = ['version', 'author', 'somethink'] // 1 value
def my_extension_order ['.pks', '.pkb']
```

And I want build somethink like that:

```
def my_index = { x ->
        return my_order.findIndexOf { x.contains(it) }
    }
def my_extension_order = { y ->
        return my_extension_order.findIndexOf { y.contains(it) }
    }

files.sort { a, b -> my_index(a) <=> my_index(b) ?: a <=> b && // sort files and extension
```

In output I want have sorted files by `my_order` and include `my_extension_order`. It should look like that:

```
def = ['version/test1.pks', 'version/test1.pkb', 'author/foo.pks', 'author/foo.pkb', 
'Somethink/foo.sql']
```

Summarizing in `file.sort` I want sort my files by 2 `ArrayList`s to get one consistent output. So how build a comparator to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do:

```
def my_index = { x -> my_order.findIndexOf { x.contains(it) } }
def my_extension_index = { y -> my_extension_order.findIndexOf { y.contains(it) } }
files.sort { a, b -> my_index(a) <=> my_index(b) ?: (my_extension_index(a) <=> my_extension_index(b) ?: a <=> b) }
```