# equivalent sortby in groovy (ruby)?

Tags: ruby, groovy

Which is the equivalent of sortby in groovy?
Which is the equivalent of sortby in groovy?

For example for doing this

```
.sort_by{|e|  e.split(";").count   }
```

please help me out.

```
 import groovyx.gpars.*
   class Test{
      public static void main(String[] args){
        def o=0
  println 'n,n,n,n,n,n,n,n'.replaceAll(/n/) { ++o }
 String fileContents = new File('/home/ffff      /tddddc.txtd').getText('UTF-8').split(';').sort { e1, e2 ->         e1.split('+').length <=> e2.split('+').length }.join(';')
     println fileContents
 }
      }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting your question. Your post seems to lack important details such as what you have already tried and example of not working code.

Comment: Can you give a sample of your input, the collection to be sorted? This makes it easier to write a solution

Comment: i put ans example but i do some errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Groovy and Java are different languages. For groovy, see this question:
[groovy sort with comparator syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574669/groovy-sort-with-comparator-syntax)

Consider this groovysh (Groovy shell) session:

```
groovy:000> x = ["a;b;c","d;e", "f;g;h;i", "j"]
===> [a;b;c, d;e, f;g;h;i, j]
groovy:000> x.sort{x,y -> x.split(";").length <=> y.split(";").length}
===> [j, d;e, a;b;c, f;g;h;i]
```

Comment: yes Im trying to do this for example but appears so muchs erros  .sort { e1, e2 -> e1.split("+").length <=> e2.split("+").length }