# Sort filenames from the output of "findFiles glob:" in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

```groovy
  steps {
    node('master') {
      script {
        def files = findFiles glob: "*/test/*.*"
        files.sort()
        echo "${files[i].name}"
      }
    }
  }
```

I have files inside test directory where filenames having a pattern `test1.csv`, `test2.csv`  ... `test100.csv`, `test101.csv` etc.

When I use `files.sort()`, Jenkins prints `test100.csv`, `test101.csv` first and then `test1.csv`.

How to sort and print like `test1`, `test2`, `test3` ... `test100` etc.

Please advice.

Comment: You need to extend sort with your own [comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574669/groovy-sort-with-comparator-syntax/35271845). [Grooovy docs](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html#_sorting) ref.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using groovy, I suggest you to do it with `sh`. Abusing groovy for simple tasks like this one is considered a bad practice, unless you need that list in other steps/operations. Eventually you just want to print it on stdout, so:

```
ls *.csv | sort -n -k 1.5
```

With `sort` you can specify the `-n, --numeric-sort` to compare according to the numerical value and a key definition `-k, --key` to sort using a key. That `1.5` means: take the first field (the whole word unless you specify a separator with `-t`) and starts comparing from the 5th character, which is the first digit after `test`.