# nextflow-groovy: how to sort files using a channel - call a function

Tags: groovy, nextflow

I've following code:

```
def chr_files = {
    a,b ->
    def numericPart = {a.replaceFirst("CHR", "").replaceAll(/.lancet_dict.vcf/,"").split('_') [0] ? a.toInteger():999 }
    numericPart(a)<=>numericPart(b)

}
def chromosomeFiles = Channel.from(["CHR20_MM-0574.lancet_dict.vcf","CHR17_MM-0574.lancet_dict.vcf","CHRX_MM-0574.lancet_dict.vcf","CHR22_MM-0574.lancet_dict.vcf","CHR1_MM-0574.lancet_dict.vcf"])

chromosomeFiles.collect{ chr_files }.view()
```

The goal is to have output as `CHR1_MM-0574.lancet_dict.vcf CHR17_MM-0574.lancet_dict.vcf CHR20_MM-0574.lancet_dict.vcf CHR22_MM-0574.lancet_dict.vcf CHRX_MM-0574.lancet_dict.vcf`

It gives a weird output as

> [Script_4368722f$_runScript_closure1@29af2082,
> Script_4368722f$_runScript_closure1@29af2082,
> Script_4368722f$_runScript_closure1@29af2082,
> Script_4368722f$_runScript_closure1@29af2082,
> Script_4368722f$_runScript_closure1@29af2082]

Second, how do I call a function to a channel as above in example? Or what should be the order?

Last, how do I extract/store/return `MM-0574` value from the files?

Comment: Please focus on a single question.  SO has a close-vote reason for
asking multiple things; so please create another question for the second
part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Death Metal.

You're writing Groovy code as if Nextflow was just Groovy. It is not. What you're doing is even considered anti-pattern, as Nextflow has channel operators to do what you're trying to do.

Channels aren't simply lists you can iterate and apply any function. If you want to do something to every element of your channel, you should use the `map` channel operator (more info [here](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#map)), for example.

You can find a solution below:

```
Channel
  .of([file("CHR20_MM-0574.lancet_dict.vcf"),
       file("CHR17_MM-0574.lancet_dict.vcf"),
       file("CHRX_MM-0574.lancet_dict.vcf"),
       file("CHR22_MM-0574.lancet_dict.vcf"),
       file("CHR1_MM-0574.lancet_dict.vcf")])
  .set { chromosomeFiles }

chromosomeFiles
  .map { it.sort { a, b ->
        def filenameA = file(a).name.replaceAll('CHR', '').replaceAll(/.lancet_dict.vcf/,"").split('_')[0]
        def filenameB = file(b).name.replaceAll('CHR', '').replaceAll(/.lancet_dict.vcf/,"").split('_')[0]
        return filenameA.compareTo(filenameB)
      }
  }
  .view()
```

If you really want a function to be called, update the final part of the snippet to:

```
def my_func(string) {
  string.replaceAll('CHR', '').replaceAll(/.lancet_dict.vcf/,"").split('_')[0]
}
chromosomeFiles
  .map { it.sort { a, b ->
        def filenameA = my_func(file(a).name)
        def filenameB = my_func(file(b).name)
        return filenameA.compareTo(filenameB)
      }
  }
  .view()
```

Comment: Sorry, I've no clue how to proceed at times with processes and steps in nextflow that led me to pick groovy. Hence, my code above in the post. One quick question - what is `it.sort {`? Is .sort a lambda function here?

Comment: No problem! Some keywords have different meanings in Nextflow, such as the `collect` channel operator. That's why you shouldn't blindly rely on Groovy when writing Nextflow code  Have you checked training.nextflow.io? Lots of good content there 

More info about `sort` here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574669/groovy-sort-with-comparator-syntax

Comment: Thanks I've watched lectures (byte-size) and checked the training modules.

Comment: Cool!  There are recordings too for the training material in multiple languages in the nf-core YouTube channel, in case you're interested.

Comment: Yes, I've been checking youtube videos for nf-core. Thank you. nextflow is immensely powerful for bioinformatics, albeit challenging. I hope to and learn and make most of nextflow!

Comment: Hi @mribeirodantas - can you please help me with nested folder output post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76898944/nextflow-groovy-how-to-emit-file-from-nested-folder-generated-by-tool

Answer (score 1):

Closures *are* first class in Groovy, but you are doing the call wrong.
`xs.collect{ f }` means something like "replace every element from `xs`
with **the function `f`**.  Using `{}` in Groovy again create a new
closure; so you are passing a function that constantly returns `f`
(ignoring the input).

So you either have to explicitly call `f` here (e.g. `xs.collect{ f it }`, which is short for `xs.collect{ f(it) }`.

Or you have to pass the closure like `xs.collect(f)` (note the regular
parenthesis).

Answer (score 1):

To sort files in a channel, one way is to use the [collect](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#collect) operator with the `sort` keyword to specify a custom comparator closure:

```
def comparator = { file1, file2 ->
    
    def matcher1 = file1.name =~ /^(?i)CHR(\d+)/
    def matcher2 = file2.name =~ /^(?i)CHR(\d+)/

    def chrom1 = matcher1.find() ? matcher1.group(1) as int : Integer.MAX_VALUE
    def chrom2 = matcher2.find() ? matcher2.group(1) as int : Integer.MAX_VALUE

    (chrom1 <=> chrom2) ?: (file1.name <=> file2.name)
}
```

```
workflow {

    Channel
        .fromPath("*.lancet_dict.vcf")
        .collect( sort: comparator )
        .view()
}
```

The above will emit a `nextflow.util.ArrayBag`, but if we just want a regular `ArrayList` (i.e. a `java.util.ArrayList`) for whatever reason, we could also use the [`toSortedList`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#tosortedlist) operator:

```
workflow {

    Channel
        .fromPath("*.lancet_dict.vcf")
        .toSortedList( comparator )
        .view()
}
```

Note that if after collecting the sorted files we then need each item emitted separately, we can flatten the collection using the [`flatten`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#flatten) operator. If instead what you have already is a channel that emits a collection of files, like your `chromosomeFiles` channel does, we can [sort](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#sort(groovy.lang.Closure)) the collection using  the [`map`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#map) operator, for example:

```
workflow {

    ...

    chromosomeFiles
        .map { it.sort( comparator ) }
        .view()
}
```

Comment: Hi @Steve, can you please help me with nested folder output post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76898944/nextflow-groovy-how-to-emit-file-from-nested-folder-generated-by-tool