# nextflow-groovy: how to emit file from nested folder generated by tool

Tags: groovy, nextflow

I'm performing variant calling step using manta tool that is a precursor to use strelka2 tool. I specify runDir. There are two steps in manta: 1) set a config file 2) run output from step 1 runworkflow.py

If in the run directory `runWorkflow.py` file is present manta won't run. So I put bash code to check and delete.

In run directory specified, it creates results folder where manta generates three folders:

```
${run_dir}/results/evidence  ${run_dir}/results/stats  ${run_dir}/results/variants
```

In variants folder there are six files:

```
${run_dir}/results/variants/candidateSmallIndels.vcf.gz      ${run_dir}/results/variants/candidateSV.vcf.gz      ${run_dir}/results/variants/diploidSV.vcf.gz      results/variants/somaticSV.vcf.gz
${run_dir}/results/variants/candidateSmallIndels.vcf.gz.tbi  ${run_dir}/results/variants/candidateSV.vcf.gz.tbi  ${run_dir}/results/variants/diploidSV.vcf.gz.tbi  ${run_dir}/results/variants/somaticSV.vcf.gz.tbi
```

Similarly other two folders generate their respective file. I'd like to emit the output from `${run_dir}/results/variants` folder as it is an input to strelka2 tool.

Please see below code

```
process manta {
errorStrategy 'retry'
    maxRetries 3

 publishDir path: "${params.outdir}/${sample_name}/manta/", mode: 'copy'
        input:
        tuple val(sample_id_tumor),path(bqsrbam_tumor, stageAs: 'manta_tumorbqsrbam/*')
        tuple val(sample_id_tumor),path(bqsrbam_bai_tumor, stageAs: 'manta_tumorbqsrbam/*')
        tuple val(sample_id_normal),path(bqsrbam_normal, stageAs: 'manta_normalbqsrbam/*')
        tuple val(sample_id_normal),path(bqsrbam_bai_normal, stageAs: 'manta_normalbqsrbam/*')

        output:
 tuple val(sample_name), path("candidateSmallIndels.vcf.gz"), emit: manta_small_indels_vcf
 tuple val(sample_name), path("candidateSmallIndels.vcf.gz.tbi"), emit: manta_small_indels_vcf_tbi
 tuple val(sample_name), path("candidateSV.vcf.gz"), emit: manta_candidateSV_vcf
 tuple val(sample_name), path("candidateSV.vcf.gz.tbi"), emit: manta_candidateSV_vcf_tbi
 tuple val(sample_name), path("diploidSV.vcf.gz"), emit: manta_diploidSV_vcf
 tuple val(sample_name), path("diploidSV.vcf.gz.tbi"), emit: manta_diploidSV_vcf_tbi
 tuple val(sample_name), path("somaticSV.vcf.gz"), emit: manta_somaticSV_vcf
 tuple val(sample_name), path("somaticSV.vcf.gz.tbi"), emit: manta_somaticSV_vcf_tbi

        script:
sample_name=sample_id_normal.split('_N')[0]

        """

mkdir -p ${params.outdir}/${sample_name}/manta/

if [ -f "${params.outdir}/${sample_name}/manta/runWorkflow.py" ] ; then
    rm "${params.outdir}/${sample_name}/manta/runWorkflow.py"
fi


/hpc/packages/configManta.py \
--normalBam ${bqsrbam_normal} \
--tumorBam ${bqsrbam_tumor} \
--referenceFasta $params.hg38genome \
--runDir ${params.outdir}/${sample_name}/manta/
        
${params.outdir}/${sample_name}/manta/./runWorkflow.py -m local -j 12 --quiet

        """
}
```

I get error:   `Missing output file(s) candidateSmallIndels.vcf.gz expected by process manta (1)`

Output of variants folder are then provided into strelka2 script that follows same steps: 1) generate runworkflow script 2) run workflow script

the output from strelka2 also follow same structure

Let me know if any other details are needed.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use absolute paths in your pipeline script. This breaks portability. Instead, `configManta.py` should be within the `bin` folder of your pipeline folder. Besides, the final relative path of your outputs should be provided to Nextflow. Not just

```
output:
  tuple path("candidateSmallIndels.vcf.gz") ...
```

but

```
output:
  tuple path("results/variants/candidateSmallIndels.vcf.gz") ...
```

**UPDATE:**
The snippet below shows you how Nextflow resolves paths even when you're creating folders within your task folder to organize the outputs.

```
process FOO {
  input:
    tuple val(filename), val(content)

  output:
    path "app_results/${filename}.txt"

  script:
    """
    mkdir -p app_results
    echo ${content} > app_results/${filename}.txt
    """
}

process BAR {
  debug true

  input:
    path content_file

  output:
    stdout

  script:
    """
    cat ${content_file}
    """
}

workflow {
  Channel
    .of(["m1.txt", "File of Marcel"],
        ["p1.txt", "File of Peter"])
    | FOO
    | BAR
}
```

Pay attention to how in the `BAR` process, I just have to say `path content_file`. The output of such a Nextflow pipeline is:

```
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 23.08.0-edge
Launching `metal.nf` [elated_aryabhata] DSL2 - revision: 46da670013
executor >  local (4)
[88/1ea6e3] process > FOO (2) [100%] 2 of 2 ✔
[09/fbf350] process > BAR (1) [100%] 2 of 2 ✔
File of Peter

File of Marcel
```

Comment: Will it emit folder or simply file? Second question - should I not provide run dir in path?  Run dir is in outdir folder`tuple path("${output_dir}/${rundir}/results/variants/candidateSmallIndels.vcf.gz") `

Comment: All these folders are created inside the `${outdir}/${rundir}/` and not work directory. Would nextflow be able to emit files that aren't in work folder?

Comment: You *must* create the files in the task dir, without providing absolute paths. If you want them to be somewhere else TOO, you use `publishDir`, but they must be in the task dir. Otherwise, you will get the error you're getting for missing output files.

Comment: Is task folder `work` directory? The manta tool specifically asks for a run directory which is why hard coded. Can you please further help how to write nextflow code in this situation? All output folders are created in the run-dir. How do I know which folder `ae` `h3` is created that could be provided as a run dir for manta?

Comment: The task folder is _within_ `./work` (if you haven't changed that). You don't have to know where the task folder is because Nextflow will take care of that for you. If process `B` receives input from `A`, Nextflow will resolve the location of outputs of `B` for `A` to use. I will update the answer with an example.

Comment: Thank you. Anything would be more helpful w.r.t to the `--runDir` flag with Manta tool. Strelka operates in similar manner, too.

Comment: Thank you for updating the post. Sorry to iterate, my concern is with `--runDir` of Manta as the `runWorkflow.py` is created inside it. How do I address it with task directory within work folder? Would nextflow automatically stage `runWorkflow.py` to its task directory? I hope I am able to express my point without any confusion. Manta tool is bottleneck.

Comment: If you have `runWorkflow.py` inside the `./bin` folder in your pipeline folder, yes, Nextflow will automatically stage it (add it to the `$PATH` in the task :))

Comment: No, `runWorkflow.py` is created by Manta tool in the `--runDir` based on input parametersm files provided for normal and tumor. I know this sounds difficult.

Comment: Yeah, this is unusual. I've never used manta, but there are nf-core modules with manta, so maybe that's a way for you to find a solution: https://nf-co.re/modules

Comment: can you please help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77304249/nextflow-module-compilation-error-in-the-process-script and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77304098/nextflow-data-not-being-published-to-output-dir-after-process-is-complete